# Как создать движение изображений в tkinter? Не могу разобраться как корректно передать в аргумент класса файл

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import time

window = Tk()

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500

canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()


class Ball:

    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, xVelocity, yVelocity, file): # ????
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image = PhotoImage(x, y, file=file.png) # ????
        self.xVelocity = xVelocity
        self.yVelocity = yVelocity

    def move(self):
        coordinates = self.canvas.coords(self.image)

        if (coordinates[2] >= (self.canvas.winfo_width()) or coordinates[0] < 0):
            self.xVelocity = -self.xVelocity
        if (coordinates[3] >= (self.canvas.winfo_height()) or coordinates[1] < 0):
            self.yVelocity = -self.yVelocity

        self.canvas.move(self.image, self.xVelocity, self.yVelocity)


picture1 = Ball(canvas, 0, 0, 1, 1, "pic1.png")
picture2 = Ball(canvas, 0, 0, 2, 2, "pic2.png")
picture3 = Ball(canvas, 0, 0, 1, 1, "pic3.png")
picture4 = Ball(canvas, 0, 0, 2, 1, "pic4.png")

while True:
    picture1.move()
    picture2.move()
    picture3.move()
    picture4.move()
    window.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.image = PhotoImage(x, y, file=f'{file}')
```

Также при `time.sleep()` вместо задержки между движениями у вас весь интерфейс будет зависать, поэтому лучше используйте `window.after(delay, func_name)` и в функции `func_name` уже вызывайте `move()`

```
def move_pictures():
    picture1.move()
    picture2.move()
    picture3.move()
    picture4.move()
    window.update()
    window.after(10, move_pictures)  # задержка в мс, функция для вызова


window.after(0, move_pictures)
window.mainloop()
```